Remix i18next translations not working in production build
I'm building a Remix application using i18next and remix-i18next for translations. While translations work correctly in development, including metadata, they fail in production showing raw keys (e.g., "meta.title", "meta.description").
Versions:

Remix: 2.14.0
remix-i18next: 6.4.1
i18next: 23.16.5
react-i18next: 15.1.1
i18next-browser-languagedetector: 8.0.0
i18next-fs-backend: 2.3.2
i18next-http-backend: 2.6.2

Configuration:
//app/utils/getLocale.ts

import i18next from "~/i18next.server";
import { getLanguagePreference } from "~/services/session.server";

export async function getLocale(request: Request): Promise<string> {
  const sessionLocale = await getLanguagePreference(request);
  const locale = sessionLocale || (await i18next.getLocale(request));

  if (!locale) {
    return "en";
  }
  
  return locale;
}


//app/i18n.ts
export default {
  supportedLngs: ["en", "es", "fr"],
  fallbackLng: "en",
  defaultNS: "common",
  ns: ["common"],  
  react: { useSuspense: false },
  interpolation: {
    escapeValue: false, 
  }
};

//app/i18next.server.ts
import Backend from "i18next-fs-backend";
import { resolve } from "node:path";
import { RemixI18Next } from "remix-i18next/server";
import i18n from "~/i18n";

let i18next = new RemixI18Next({
  detection: {
    supportedLanguages: i18n.supportedLngs,
    fallbackLanguage: i18n.fallbackLng,
  },
  i18next: {
    ...i18n,
    backend: {
      loadPath: resolve("./public/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json"),
    },
  },

  plugins: [Backend],
});

export default i18next;

app/routes/_index.tsx
import { json } from "@remix-run/react";
import type { LoaderFunctionArgs, MetaFunction } from "@remix-run/node";
import { LoaderData } from "~types/*";
import i18next from "~/i18next.server";
import { getLocale } from "~/utils/getLocale";

export const handle = { i18n: "home" };

export async function loader({ request }: LoaderFunctionArgs) {
  const locale = await getLocale(request);
  const t = await i18next.getFixedT(locale, "home", { keyPrefix: "meta" });

  const title = t("title")
  const description = t("description")

  console.log({ title, description })

  return json<LoaderData>({
    translations: {
      locale,
      title: t("title"),
      description: t("description"),
      ogTitle: t("ogTitle"),
      ogDescription: t("ogDescription"),
      twitterTitle: t("twitterTitle"),
      twitterDescription: t("twitterDescription"),
    },
  });
}

export const meta: MetaFunction<typeof loader> = ({ data }) => {
  const baseUrl = "https://example.com";

  console.log({Translation: data?.translations });

  if (!data?.translations) {
    console.error("No translations data available");
    return [{ title: "Fallback Title" }];
  }

  return [
    { title: data?.translations.title },
    {
      name: "description",
      content: data?.translations.description,
    },
    { property: "og:title", content: data?.translations.ogTitle },
    {
      property: "og:description",
      content: data?.translations.ogDescription,
    },
    { property: "og:image", content: "/images/banner.jpg" },
    { property: "og:url", content: "https://example.com" },
    { name: "twitter:card", content: "summary_large_image" },
    {
      name: "twitter:title",
      content: data?.translations.twitterTitle,
    },
    {
      name: "twitter:description",
      content: data?.translations.twitterDescription,
    },
    { name: "twitter:image", content: "/banners/banner.jpg" },

    { name: "robots", content: "index, follow, max-image-preview:large" },
    { name: "language", content: data?.translations.locale },
    { name: "revisit-after", content: "1 day" },

    { tagName: "link", rel: "canonical", href: baseUrl },
  ];
};

// the rest of the code

I've tried:

Building locally (works fine)
Production (displaying raw keys)

How can I fix the translation issues in the production environment? Lastly, I have pushed everything including the locale files to remote github. The directory looks like this:
public/
  locales/
    en/
      common.json
      home.json
    es/
      ...
    fr/
      ...

//public/locales/en/common.json
{
  "meta": {
    "title": "Example Title",
    "description": "Example Description"
    // ... other translations
  }
}


I am expecting to get an answer on why metadata translation is not working in the production.
